# Render-blocking fonts

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, google-font-api

For some reason, **[a huge list of fonts](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins%3A100%2C100i%2C200%2C200i%2C300%2C300i%2C400%2C400i%2C500%2C500i%2C600%2C600i%2C700%2C700i%2C800%2C800i%2C900%2C900i%7CPoppins%3A100%2C100i%2C200%2C200i%2C300%2C300i%2C400%2C400i%2C500%2C500i%2C600%2C600i%2C700%2C700i%2C800%2C800i%2C900%2C900i&display=swap) is being downloaded from Google Fonts** on [my Wordpress website (staging site is linked)](https://pruebas.imthemoisturizer.com), and Google PageSpeed Insights identifies it as Render-blocking resources.

The thing is I would basically just need the Poppins 300, 500, 600 on Italics and Regular, so I had embedded the fonts as Google states, linking to them on the header of the site, but I deleted that link and realized that the fonts are still working, so I assume that the Wordpress Theme must be the one responsible for this.

My question is, **how could I reduce the amount of fonts so that only the truly necessary ones are downloaded and thus minimize those render-blocking resources?**

Thanks a lot for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to install a plugin you can select which fonts you use (including the font-weight) by this [lightweight plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/host-webfonts-local/) and it will also combine - minimize the rest of the fonts so you will have less DNS requests for a faster web page.

[image]

Comment: This just solved it, I didn't know the plugin but it's such a great tool, thanks you so much for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

Regenerate the embed link by selecting only the fonts you need:
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins?selection.family=Caveat

Comment: The thing is I originally loaded the fonts on my header, but after deleting the embed link they still load correctly, I believe because the theme itself may be doing it, so I'm not sure if there's a way to prevent it from loading the excessive amount of fonts it does.